# Connect to website with Tor with a specific IP

Tags: ip-address

There is a website I want to connect to via a specific IP. It uses CluodFlare and I am constantly having to deal with the captcha. Via a normal browser I can connect to the website by adding the site and the real IP to my /etc/hosts like:

```
188.188.188.34   domain.info
```

And this bypasses CloudFlare. However, I am unable to connect to the website via Tor.

Is there a way I can tell tor to connect to this domain on the real IP?

Comment: Have you tried asking the site operators to loosen the restrictions?  There are settings within the Cloudflare control panel that allow you to dial back these things.

Comment: Luckily CloudFlare has stopped going crazy. It was nuts last week.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just connect to this website with your real IP address, you can add it to `$no_proxy` environment variable. See this: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you're using a firewall and transparent proxy mode for tor, it can be done ASA destination-based exception. The tor itself can not have it done neither via config, nor via environment cars, and this is right : it's another network stack components duty to perform the task you need